# Http failure during parsing in lazy module in NativeScript with Angular

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm having an error trying to send a post http request in a lazy module using Nativescript 6.1.1 with Angular 8:

```
ERROR {


"headers": {
    "normalizedNames": {},
    "lazyUpdate": null,
    "headers": {}
  },
  "status": 200,
  "statusText": "Unknown Error",
  "url": "http://192.168.1.61:45455/geolocation",
  "ok": false,
  "name": "HttpErrorResponse",
  "message": "Http failure during parsing for http://192.168.1.61:45455/geolocation",
  "error": {}
}
```

The response I get in Chrome network is:

}�AO� ��p��ސ%�3q�:wY<�T�H:^����tN)qY�������$��㨬>��f�"�Iݮ9�R��
���{
F���v�]a����4L���si�0�ܟMi'0O�r�-��-[{��{�TV\�_I�ΤP�߼��'�!��6�>�A��MT++��N���X4M� F��z�;�x}'5t8��^�%�����Փ�8�T03��������s��+4"Z��9�F)��o��

As you can see, I'm testing in a local backend. However, the weird thing is that I have used the service 3 times with different endpoints and I get correct answers. The only difference is that the previous times I made the call from a component in app.module, and for this time I'm making the call in a lazy module.

I imported NativeScriptHttpClientModule in the lazy module as I did it in the app.module. I tested the request using postman and I'm getting answer correctly, so it isn't an error from the backend.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: By default the response is expected to be JSON, if your response is not JSON you should modify the behavior by modifying observe attribute.

Comment: What is your response type from the api ?

Comment: The response is JSON, additionally I added the content type header with application/json. And as I said, I make 3 calls to the backend successfully in the app module, the error occurs when I make the call from a lazy loading module, at least is the only difference I see

Comment: I found the issue, my answer for this service is compressed, any way to make it works?